# Set content offset of presented view controller's scroll view before it's presented?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a container `scrollView` that contains a regular collection view and collection view cells inside of it (There are a couple custom views inside of it that aren't collection view cells, hence why I have a container scroll view and not just a collection view).

When a user taps a cell, I instantiate and present a view controller programmatically:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("second") as! SecondViewController
self.presentViewController(secondVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

That works great. Now, I want to transition back to the original view controller at a certain content offset. So I have a method in my second view controller to perform this transition back:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let firstVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("first") as! FirstViewController
// There's an IBOutlet for my containerScrollView
firstVC.containerScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 500, y: 0), animated: false)
self.presentViewController(firstVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

The transition back to `firstVC` performs fine, but it always starts at the beginning of the container scroll view in `firstVC` rather than what I set for the custom content offset. I've checked to make sure that the `containerScrollView` property on the `firstVC` exists before I try setting the content offset, and it does exist. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Your code isnt "transitioning back" you are presenting a new instance of firstvc on top of the existing first and second Vcs. You should use `dismissViewComtroller` to go back

Comment: I don't understand what you said.

Comment: Sorry. Premature enter. I have edited it

Comment: Ah, so when I call `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` the presented view controller keeps a reference to which view controller called it? If you move your comment to an answer I can accept it.